# Kendo format numbers in grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid customosed and I want to format some cells to have decimal type, to calculate a sum in the footer of the grid. After all I want to format numbers with spaces for each 000s. Does anybody have any idea what is the best way of doing that?

This is already done, but I want to make it using kendo framework functionality, if exist..

Answer (score 0):

What you can use is the [change](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#events-change) event of the DataSource. When an item value has changed you can go and update that sum in the footer you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The footer sum is completely doable.

When it comes to the decimal separator, it is recommended that you set the Kendo culture to a culture that closely matches what you're trying to do, but you could also define a custom culture or hack it by manipulating the current/default culture.

Here's a jsbin with an example of footer sums and 'hacking' the culture to have space as decimal separator:

http://jsbin.com/weqidicajo/1/edit